# Calculating the Time Complexity of nested loop with logarithmic increase

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am learning at my own pace online. I was solving some examples but I can't wrap my mind around this one:

```
while(i<n)
{
     for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
         sum = sum + 1;
     i *=2;
}
```

I think the answer should be 2^n but my friend says nlog(n)

Can someone find the big-O for this loop and explain to me how to do so?

Answer (score 3):

The outer loop will enter it's body `log2(n)` times, because `i` is increasing exponentially and thereby reaches the end `n` faster and faster. For example, if `n` were `1024`, it would need only 10 iterations, with `n=65536`, it were 16 iterations. The accurate count is `log2(n)`, but in terms of runtime complexity the logarithmic behaviour is enough. So here the complexity is `O(log(n))`.

The inner loop `for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)`, each time when evaluated, will run to the corresponding `i`. It can be shown that the average run width is about `n / log2(n)`, since `i` is `1`, `2`, `4`, ... `n` with `log2(n)` steps. For example, if `n` is `31`, `i` is `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`, the sum is `31` with `5` steps. So it is permissible to take complexity `O(n/log(n))` here.

The overal complexity is then `O(log(n)*n/log(n))`, which is `O(n)`.

Comment: @DAle: you are right; this changes the result significantly.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume without loss of generality that `N` is equal to `2^k + 1`. We need to find the number of iterations of the inner loop. There will be `k` iterations of outer loop with `2^0, 2^1, ..., 2^k` iterations of the inner loop. Let's sum up this values.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's `n`.

if `n=2^k` then while complexity is k,

second loop : `2^1 + 2^2 + ... 2^k = 2^(k+1)-1 ~= 2^(k+1)`

`2^(k+1) = 2*n`